# On submit - page to refresh back to certain point on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a contact form that is part of a homepage and when the user clicks 'contact us' the contact form pops out.  What I would like to achieve is that when the user clicks the submit button on the contact form the page will refresh and then bring the user straight back to the contact form.

Is there a way in which this can be done using javascript/jquery/php maybe using an ID as an anchor point?

I have looked online to see if there are any direct answers to this and unfortunately I haven't had any luck so any help you can give would be great.  Also some example code would be awesome :)

Comment: Instead of doing a "normal" form post, use Ajax and the user won't be redirected away at all.

Comment: @Coder does the page have to refresh?

Comment: Do you know bootstrap modal?

Comment: Yes, the page needs to refresh as the form is being submitted through PHP and I would like to redirect the user back to the contact form in order to display a success message on the form once the php has ran successfully

Comment: With Ajax, the page doesn't _have to_ refresh at all, since that will allow you to post the form asynchronous in the background using JS. When the request is done, you can simply show the user the correct response (using JS)

Comment: Thanks, so am I still able to display the success message after the php has been run.  What I am trying to achieve is only displaying the success message once the php has been successful as I do not want to misinform the user that the message has been successful if indeed it has not.

Comment: If you submit in Ajax to your php script, with  jquery  .done() event you capture the fact that the form has been submitted, and then you can in jquery display a success message...all this without refreshing the page...

Comment: Wonder how you solved that..

Answer (score 1):

Wich such code it can work :

```
$("#submit_form_button").click( function() {
    // we wait 1 second, so that the form has been submitted in ajax...
    setTimeout(function(){ location = window.location.href + "?action=display_form" }, 1000);

  // put "?action=display_form" or "&action=display_form" according the fact the page has already or not a ?xxx=yyy parameter
});
```

And replace `submit_form_button` with the ID of the submit button

So after the form is submitted, the page refreshes with the new parameter `action=display_form`, and then in your page you can add the following code :

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};


$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (getUrlParameter('action') =="display_form") {
         // i launch the JS code for redisplay me form here 
         // (using jquery to set the contact form CSS property to 'display: block;')
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  It just takes me back to the home page and not back into the contact form.

Comment: you want to reopen the form in his popup ?

Comment: yes.  so the form is displayed once the 'contact us' button is pressed on the home page.  The form is a pop out form that sits over the top of the homepage  (performed by using jquery to set the contact form CSS property to 'display: block;')

Comment: No joy I'm afraid - script runs with no errors on the console but still takes me back to the home page :(  Maybe best to use Ajax on this one and avoid altogether having to refresh the page

Comment: Ajax will be clearly better !  if you submit in Ajax to your php script, with jquery .done() event you capture the fact that the form has been submitted, and then you can in jquery display a success message...all this without refreshing the page.